# Parse function suddenly returning invalid json

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

since a couple of hours ago all my parse functions have been returning invalid json. Nothing to do with the cloud code... I even tried rolling it back. I'm on the android platform and haven't made any game breaking changes to it..

For example,
I have a login function...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("loginuser", function(request, response){

    var useremail = request.params.useremail;
    var userpassword = request.params.userpassword;
    var usersource = request.params.usersource;

    Parse.User.logIn(useremail, userpassword,{
        success:function(user){
            // Sets either candidate or business to be true depending on condition
            if (usersource == "candidate"){
                user.set("candidate", true);
            } else if (usersource == "business"){
                user.set("business", true);
            }
            user.save(null, {
                // login success & return
                success: function(user){
                    response.success(user);
                }, error: function(error){
                    response.error(error);
                }
            });
        },
        error:function(user, error){
            // login failure
            response.error(user, error);
        }
    });
});
```

With no change to it... it suddenly starts throwing error:

```
01-05 22:37:30.175 1052-1052/recruitr.recruitr E/Login error: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
01-05 22:37:46.045 1052-1052/recruitr.recruitr E/Signup Error: com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
```

Does anyone know why?

EDIT:

Ran debugger and it pops this out when the error message shows up:

```
this = {LoginActivity$4@4619} 
cancel = {boolean[1]@4623} 
logincredentials = {HashMap@4624}  size = 3
parseUser = null
e = {ParseRequest$ParseRequestException@4625} "com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response"
 isPermanentFailure = false
 code = 100
 cause = {JSONException@4630} "org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
  cause = {JSONException@4630} "org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
  detailMessage = {String@4638} "Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"
  stackState = {long[34]@4639} 
  stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]@4633} 
  suppressedExceptions = {Collections$EmptyList@4634}  size = 0
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@497} "class org.json.JSONException"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1960135782
 detailMessage = {String@4631} "bad json response"
 stackState = {long[30]@4632} 
 stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[0]@4633} 
 suppressedExceptions = {Collections$EmptyList@4634}  size = 0
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4592} "class com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException"
 shadow$_monitor_ = -2123277170
```

Comment: Can you see, using developer tools network tab, the raw json data?

Comment: Nope, see updated... I see error code 100. According to the parse website http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm 100 means connection failed... but however it is failing on my phone as well. Could it be parse having problems? However my other apps don't have problems...

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

The Android Parse SDK was having problems with a new update. Parse was not actually initializing in the code at all (keys weren't working/initialization was not working)

Fix the error by changing the dependency:

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.0'
```

Both seem to work flawlessly as of this moment in time.